# How to implement scarlet websocket library with okhttp in Java?

Tags: kotlin, websocket, okhttp

I wanted to know if there is any java implementation of Scarlet web socket library.

```
 @EchoBotScope
 @Component(modules = [(EchoBotComponent.EchoBotModule::class)], dependencies = [(EchoBotComponent.Dependency::class)])
interface EchoBotComponent {

    fun inject(echoBotFragment: EchoBotFragment)

    interface Dependency {
        fun application(): Application
    }

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        fun dependency(dependency: Dependency): Builder

        fun build(): EchoBotComponent
    }

    @Module
    class EchoBotModule {
        @Provides
        @EchoBotScope
        fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC))
            .build()

        @Provides
        @EchoBotScope
        fun provideLifecycle(application: Application, loggedInLifecycle: LoggedInLifecycle): Lifecycle =
            AndroidLifecycle.ofApplicationForeground(application)
                .combineWith(loggedInLifecycle)

        @Provides
        @EchoBotScope
        fun provideEchoService(client: OkHttpClient, lifecycle: Lifecycle): EchoService {
            val scarlet = Scarlet.Builder()
                .webSocketFactory(client.newWebSocketFactory("wss://demos.kaazing.com/echo"))
                .lifecycle(lifecycle)
                .addMessageAdapterFactory(BitmapMessageAdapter.Factory())
                .addStreamAdapterFactory(RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory())
                .build()
            return scarlet.create()
        }
    }

    interface ComponentProvider {
        val echoBotComponent: EchoBotComponent
    }
}
```

How can customize the demo app to make my own okhttp WebSocket client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming here that you want to use scarlet in a java project. First of all, the version you are using is outdated. Please find the latest version of scarlet library [here](https://github.com/Tinder/Scarlet/tree/0.2.x). It has breaking changes and you will need to migrate your code.

You can use the scarlet library in a java project as is without depending on the kotlin specific modules like`scarlet-stream-adapter-coroutines`. An example `EchoBotModule` implementation in java is given below.

```
  @Module
class EchoBotModule {
    @Provides
    @EchoBotScope
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor()
                        .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC))
                .build();
    }


    @Provides
    @EchoBotScope
    Lifecycle provideLifecycle(Application application, LoggedInLifecycle loggedInLifecycle) {
        return AndroidLifecycle.ofApplicationForeground(application)
                .combineWith(loggedInLifecycle);
    }

    @Provides
    @EchoBotScope
    EchoService provideEchoService(OkHttpClient client, Lifecycle lifecycle) {
        Protocol pr = new OkHttpWebSocket(client, new OkHttpWebSocket.SimpleRequestFactory(
                () -> new Request.Builder().url("wss://demos.kaazing.com/echo").build(),
                () -> ShutdownReason.GRACEFUL
        ));

        List<MessageAdapter.Factory> messageAdapterFactories = Collections.singletonList(new BitmapMessageAdapter.Factory());

        List<StreamAdapter.Factory> streamAdapterFactories = Collections.singletonList(new RxJava2StreamAdapterFactory());

        Scarlet.Configuration configuration = new Scarlet.Configuration(lifecycle, null, streamAdapterFactories, messageAdapterFactories, false);

        Scarlet scarlet = new Scarlet(pr, configuration);
        return scarlet.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: hey, can you provide the full java example if you have implemented it?

Comment: Sorry I don't have a full java implementation. But will be happy to help if you hit any technical bottlenecks along the way.